# How to force window.open() to open new tabs, whenever the browser supports them?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have developed a Web site one of whose requirements was that every link open in a new window or tab. For obvious reasons, it is preferable that several tabs, instead of several windows be created. How do I make JavaScript's `window.open()` function always open a new tab whenever the browser supports them, regardless of other variables (such as whether the user has configured the browser to open new windows rather than tabs)?

Comment: Can I have the address to this site, so I can make sure I never visit it?

Comment: Haha. Don't worry. It's an Intranet site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override the user's settings. Quite frankly, I would be appalled if you could.

What makes your site special enough that what YOU want it to do is more important than what I want my computer to do?

Comment: Maybe you wouldn't think the same if, by using the Web site in a rather trivial way, you'd open 10+ windows.

Comment: @Eduado - If that we're the case, it opening new windows were annoying me, I would change **my** settings to tabs. The point still stands - you cant dictate how a user should use their computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the browser's own user has complete control of this behavior. At least, the user has such control if she chose the right browser :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the handling of popups is determined by the browser and its user-defined settings. There'd be no point in giving people the option to choose how pop-ups are opened if web developers could bypass them entirely.